# Set a List as index in pandas with expansion as a new row

Tags: python, pandas

Hi i have the following Data frame.

```
    Number            Text
0   [12, 3]          Apple
1   [2222, 4, 5]     Banana
2   [3]              Guava
```

I require to Set_index of the dataframe such that each entry in the Number columns has a row entry as follows

```
           Text
Number
12         Apple
3          Apple
2222       Banana
4          Banana
5          Banana
3          Guava
```

In a nutshell, to make a list the index and expanding each of its entries to a row.

Answer (score 0):

Try `explode`:

```
df.explode('Number').set_index('Number')
```